# Targeting parent div (one level above child with class)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following markup:

```html
<div>
  <div class="richtext">
    dummy text
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to use JQuery to achieve the following:

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="richtext">
    dummy text
  </div>
</div>
```

To do this, I've done the following:

```
$(".richtext").prev('div').css('width','100%');
```

But it doesn't add the inline style to the `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.parent()` to get the parent.

```
$(".richtext").parent().css('width','100%');
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `.parent()`

`$(".richtext").parent().css('width','100%');`

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/m5wf7ur9/2/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".richtext").parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> Start parent DIV
  <div class="richtext">
    dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text
  </div>
  End parent DIV
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterated through the selected

```js
$('div.richtext').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().css("color", "red");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="richtext">
    dummy text
  </div>
</div>
```